# Speeding up iteration over dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that basically consists of three columns: group, timestamp, value.

[image]

I created the following for loop that will iterate through the data frame and run tests to see if the values are acceptable or not. For example, if not enough time has passed between the timestamps to account for the value, then it is tagged as potentially bad data.

The only caveat here is that values should not always be compared to the previous value, but rather the last 'good' value within the group. Thus the reason I went with the loop.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this without the loop, or are there inefficiencies in the loop that would help speed it up?

```
dfy = pd.DataFrame(index=dfx.index,columns = ['gvalue','quality'])
for row in df.itertuples():

    thisgroup = row[1]
    thistimestamp = row[2]
    thisvalue = row[3]
    qualitytag = ''
    qualitytest = True

    if prevgroup == thisgroup:
        ts_gap = thistimestamp - goodtimestamp
        hour_gap = (thisvalue - goodvalue) * 3600

        if hour_gap < 0:
            qualitytag = 'H'
            qualitytest = False
        elif hour_gap > ts_gap:
            qualitytag = 'A'
            qualitytest = False
        elif hour_gap >= 86400
            qualitytag = 'U'
            qualitytest = False

    #if tests pass, update good values
    if qualitytest:
        goodvalue = thisvalue
        goodtimestamp = thistimestamp

    #save good values to y dataframe
    dfy.iat[row[0],0] = goodvalue
    dfy.iat[row[0],1] = qualitytag

    prevgroup = thisgroup

df = dfx.join(dfy)
```

Comment: You can take a look at [this link](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6), it helped me out when I was trying to optimize my code for pandas - its a general outline on various ways you can iterate over your dataframe with a examples for each method